# How to find what value this code returns without a computer?

Tags: java

What value does mystery(12345678) return?

```
public String mystery(int n)
 {
 String soln = “”;
 while (n > 0)
 {
 soln = n % 10 + soln;
 n = n / 100;
 }
 return soln;
 }
```

The answers are:
a) “1357”
b) “2468”
c) “7531”
d) “8642”
e) It causes a run-time error.

edit: I know the answer is b) from compiling but not sure how it works.

Comment: Compile and learn. We don't do homework!

Comment: If you run through the code in your head and work out what all the variables are where do you get stuck?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can see that it's a loop of adding the one's digit of n to the first index of the string, then dividing n by 100. Eventually, you get to 2468

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this?